# Disable evil-mode when git-timemachine mode is activated

Tags: git, evil

How do I disable `evil-mode` in a buffer in which `git-timemachine` is activated?

Comment: `evil-mode` is a global minor mode, what you're probably after is not disabling it alltogether (since that would disable it anywhere else, too).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is directly from the EVIL developer Frank Fischer,

I tested on Emacs24.4 with latest evil1.0.9+. Most evil key bindings still works, but we let git-timemachine's hotkeys take priority.

```
;; @see https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/511/let-certain-minor-modes-key-bindings
(eval-after-load 'git-timemachine
  '(progn
     (evil-make-overriding-map git-timemachine-mode-map 'normal)
     ;; force update evil keymaps after git-timemachine-mode loaded
     (add-hook 'git-timemachine-mode-hook #'evil-normalize-keymaps)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) will toggle `evil-local-mode`: disabling it when you enable `git-timemachine-mode`, and enabling it when you turn off `git-timemachine-mode`:

```
(defadvice git-timemachine-mode (after toggle-evil activate)
  "Turn off `evil-local-mode' when enabling
`git-timemachine-mode', and turn it back on when disabling
`git-timemachine-mode'."
  (evil-local-mode (if git-timemachine-mode -1 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sadly it's not working though. Could it be because git-timemachine-mode is activated by calling git-timemachine (i.e. without -mode at the end)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want evil to be in emacs mode when you launch git-timemachine, try that: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Evil#Enter_an_emacs_mode_in_a_given_state

In a nutshell, try

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'git-timemachine 'emacs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work if, as @wasamusa notes, `git-timemachine` is a minor mode rather than a major mode.

Comment: That's totally not what I was hinting at.  But thanks for the information, that calls for a different way of solving it.